# Python 3.6: Issue with looping through simple text file with identical strings in each row

Tags: python-3.x

---

Very new to python am I am having an issue reading through a small text file.  As you can see I am trying to print a line of text and its index row number.

The text file looks like this:

```
This is a test ABC

This is a test ABC

This is a test ABC

This is a test ABC

This is a test CBA
```

Code:

```
with open ("Loop_test.txt") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    for row in text:
        if "test" in row:
        print (row, text.index(row))
```

The problem is that this outputs:

```
This is a test ABC
0

This is a test ABC
0

This is a test ABC
0

This is a test ABC
0

This is a test CBA
4
```

..so it appears to print the same row 4 times rather than recognizing each one independently. The problem is that with another file i am using I want to use the index of those first 4 rows as a reference point for other rows in the file.  I know I am being thick here, I just cant see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
    with open("test.txt") as f:
        for i, row in enumerate(f):
            if "test" in row:
                print i, row
```

`for row in f:` is a pythonic way to read a textfile line by line. Here, you need an index, so we use `enumerate`.

Comment: Got it, thanks, exactly what I need.   I also realised that by calling text.index(row)  python was simply matching the first one it found of the 4 identical lines and returning that row again and again. Enumerate does the job :)

Answer (score 0):

You've made an indentation error: that last line in your program needs to be indented. As it is, python ignores the `if "test" in row:` and prints anyway.

Correction:

```
with open ("Loop_test.txt") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    for row in text:
        if "test" in row:
            print (row, text.index(row))
```

Comment: yes, sorry first time posting  - having fun with the formatting.